# How to Access Public Class Methods for Hash in IRB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, irb

Beginning RoR programmer here...

In IRB, I have a hash that is retrieved from a database table.  I want to perform Hash class methods on this hash (.select, .keys, etc.) but when I try to do that I get NoMethodError.  What fundamental concept am I missing here?

EDIT: Here's the console output

```
2.0.0-p247 :020 > vote_record.keys                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
NoMethodError: undefined method `keys' for #<Vote:0x00000002736f98>                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activemodel-       4.0.0/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:436:in `method_missing'                                                                                                                                          
    from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:131:in `method_missing'                                                                                                                                        
    from (irb):20                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'                                                                                                                                                               
    from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'                                                                                                                                                                
    from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:64:in `<top (required)>'                                                                                                                                                            
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>
```

Comment: Paste your console output.

Comment: Those are instance methods, not class methods. Use `my_hash.keys`

Comment: @Marek edited to include console output

Comment: @Sergio - sorry, I'd like to perform hash instance methods, but as you can see from the console output I just added, I'm not able to do that.

Comment: Well, because it's a `Vote`, not a hash.

Comment: What is your model name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `vote_record` isn't a `Hash`, but `Vote` (inheriting from `ActiveRecord::Base` class) instance.

Comment: Okay, I'll use .attributes to convert to hash first.  Thanks!